# Div filtering using jquery

Tags: jquery, filtering, product

Hi I'd like to make a div filter using multiple checkboxes, those checkboxes have value the div have classes.
My js is comparing thoses value and classes and display the similar ones.
I'd like to combine those checkboxes. For example when glutenitoon and maidoton is checked, the element with only maidoton or only glutenitoon should not be shown.

Here is the codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYgpda

edit : **solution here** > http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdaGwM

```
<div id="filters">
        <input type="checkbox" name="gluteeniton" value="gluteeniton" id="filter-gluteeniton">Gluteeniton
        <input type="checkbox" name="laktoositon" value="laktoositon" id="filter-laktoositon">Laktoositon
        <input type="checkbox" name="vahalaktoosinen" value="vahalaktoosinen" id="filter-vahalaktoosinen">Vähälaktoosinen
        <input type="checkbox" name="maidoton" value="maidoton" id="filter-maidoton">Maidoton
        <input type="checkbox" name="soijaton" value="soijaton" id="filter-soijaton">Soijaton
    </div>

    <div class="filtered-products">                    
        <div class="element gluteeniton laktoositon maidoton">gluteeniton laktoositon maidoton</div>
        <div class="element laktoositon maidoton">laktoositon maidoton</div>
        <div class="element gluteeniton">gluteeniton</div>
        <div class="element soijaton">Soijaton</div>
        <div class="element maidoton soijaton">Maidoton Soijaton</div>
        <div class="element maidoton">Maidoton</div>
        <div class="element laktoositon">Laktoositon</div>
    </div>   



$(".element").hide();
$("#filters input").click(function() { 
        var checked = $("#filters input ").is(':checked');
        if (checked) {

            $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                $("." + $(this).val()).show();
            });
        }
        else {
        $(".element").hide();
        }    

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've got your question right, the following should be the solution. Please check with this chunk of codes once

```
$(".element").hide();
$("#filters input").click(function() { 
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
if (checked) {


    $("#filters input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
        $("." + $(this).val()).show();
    });
}
else {

    $(".element."+$(this).val()).hide();
    $("#filters input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
        $("." + $(this).val()).show();
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working to me except that you need to hide all the boxes you've shown on each click then show those that match. This should work.

```
$(".element").hide();
$("#filters input").click(function() { 
    $(".element").hide();
    var checked = $("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join('.');
    $('.element.' + checked).show();
});
```

Edit: changed the code to fit requirements of strict matching. To select elements that have multiple classes you just list all the classes in your selector linked with a period. (e.g. $('.class1.class2.class3)) The Map function returns all the results of it's inner function ( in this case the value) as an array. If you then join the array with a period as a separator you have the selector you need.

If you would like a really cool jquery filtering and sorting plugin so you don't have to try to write it yourself take a look at Quicksand: http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

Comment: Hi Gregg, yes it's working but only if you use a single checkbox.
When you use two or more checkboxes, I'd like that the filter works strictly.
The element should have strictly those two or more selected values.
Quicksand is working as radio button, I need checkboxes.

Comment: See my edited answer. This works for strict filtering. The Quicksand filter will work for checkboxes as well. and with strict filtering. I'm using it on this page. https://www.deaconess.com/Find-a-Doctor/Deaconess-Clinic-Primary-Care.aspx . Multiple selections within a group will show all that match any selected. But selections across different groups will only show those that have a match in all groups. It's very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change completely the method and use data- attributes instead 
the answer is here
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvNjGr

```
$('#filters').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
                    var $lis = $('.filtered-products > div'),
                        $checked = $('input:checked');
                    if ($checked.length)
                    {                           
                        var selector = '';
                        $($checked).each(function(index, element){                            
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + element.id + "']";                            
                        });                        
                        $lis.hide();                        
                        $('.filtered-products > div').filter(selector).show();             
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $lis.show();
                    }
                });
```